# Power BI count if at least one row contains value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Trying to create a measure that will count distinct projects that have hit at least one mark
It seems like a simple question but whatever I try in DAX nothing sticks.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **measure** as below-

```
total project = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(your_table_name[project]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[mark1] +
        your_table_name[mark2] + 
        your_table_name[mark3] +
        your_table_name[mark4] +
        your_table_name[mark5] >= 1
    )
)
```

You can use the above **measure** in a **CARD** to get the total count of Project name at least has 1 mark in the row. For your sample data, you will get the result 3 (A,C,D).